# Google web font

Tags: google, css, fonts

Please suggest me Google web font similar to following image,

[image]

Comment: font-name: Franklin

Comment: It would help if you'd give some detail as to why you can't find this yourself. What research have you done? When I go to [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), without no filtering, the first font listed(Istok Web) is pretty close to Franklin. Doesn't have the double-story "g" and the top of the "l" is notched, but you're giving no context for how picky you're going to be about such details. Franklin's pretty plain and a lot could work. GWF does have another named Francois which is a direct revival of Franklin, but there's only one weight and it's heavier than in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The most similar one I found is this one: **Quattrocento Sans**, by Pablo Impallari